# Is there a Challenge Mode in X & Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

The previous generation of games introduced Challenge Mode and Easy Mode, which had to be unlocked in Black 2 & White 2, respectively.

Is there any similar mechanic in X & Y, either as a mode to start in or enable mid-game? All I have seen is speculation from before the games were released.

Answer (score 1):

Having completed the game and done much of the postgame stuff, I belive I can say with a fair degree of confidence that **no there is no different difficulty setting**.

Answer (score -1):

SO far, I haven't found any options in the settings or any information about such possibility after beating the game.

If there was something like this - few diffrent dificuities of game - **online competition and trading wouldn't be possible**. Imagine trade beetween Easy and Challenge and earning best Pokemon before 1st gym...

I believe that there is only one level of dificulty which is casual (to say the least) for chalenge they give certain optional mechanics like online battles or Battle Maison in Kiloude City.

Comment: There were competitive battles and trading in Black/White as well though, so I don't understand how this would be a problem. and the problem of 'all powerful' Pokemon before the first gym would be the same as its always been - the Pokemon wouldn't listen to you ;)